# prevent kill frame

Tags: javascript, html

instead of asking how to kill frame. i interested to know what technique can be used to prevent an iframe inside a page from been killed by "frame killer"

Answer (score 9):

There is always, unfortunately a way to get round frame killers, because of the way they work. (The site that is being framed can usually, however, display a warning).

See Jeff Atwood's "[disturbing revelation](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001277.html)".

A few choice excerpt:

> **If an evil website decides it's going
>   to frame your website, you will be
>   framed. Period.** Frame-busting is
>   nothing more than a false sense of
>   security; it doesn't work.

Frame busting code (from the linked Stack Overflow challenge):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prevent_bust = 0  
    window.onbeforeunload = function() { prevent_bust++ }  
    setInterval(function() {  
      if (prevent_bust > 0) {  
        prevent_bust -= 2  
        window.top.location = 'http://server-which-responds-with-204.com'  
      }  
    }, 1)  
</script>
```

This code does the following:

- increments a counter every time the
  browser attempts to navigate away
  from the current page, via the
  window.onbeforeonload event handler
- sets up a timer that fires every
  millisecond via setInterval(), and if
  it sees the counter incremented,
  changes the current location to a
  server of the attacker's control
- that server serves up a page with
  HTTP status code 204, which does not
  cause the browser to navigate
  anywhere

Answer (score 2):

Happily, there is nothing that works outside of Internet Explorer (which lets JS be disabled in iframes as a security feature).

If the author of a site doesn't want their pages framed, then that is their choice.